# Bundler raises ThreadError exceptions while running `bundle install`

Tags: ruby, bundler

First, some background info, I'm attempting to run `bundle install` on a remote bluehost server. I believe the problem is the number of threads that bundler makes is more than I'm allowed for the server, although I'm not really sure. Here's me running `bundle install --verbose`:

```
$ bundle install --verbose
Running `bundle install --verbose` with bundler 1.13.6
Found changes from the lockfile, re-resolving dependencies because the list of sources changed, the dependencies in your gemfile changed, you added a new platform to your gemfile
HTTP GET https://index.rubygems.org/versions
HTTP 304 Not Modified https://index.rubygems.org/versions
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Looking up gems ["rails", "sqlite3", "sass-rails", "uglifier", "coffee-rails", "jquery-rails", "turbolinks", "jbuilder", "sdoc", "bcrypt", "byebug", "web-console", "spring"]
Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): ThreadError can't create Thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
Looking up gems ["rails", "sqlite3", "sass-rails", "uglifier", "coffee-rails", "jquery-rails", "turbolinks", "jbuilder", "sdoc", "bcrypt", "byebug", "web-console", "spring"]
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): ThreadError can't create Thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
Looking up gems ["rails", "sqlite3", "sass-rails", "uglifier", "coffee-rails", "jquery-rails", "turbolinks", "jbuilder", "sdoc", "bcrypt", "byebug", "web-console", "spring"]
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): ThreadError can't create Thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
Looking up gems ["rails", "sqlite3", "sass-rails", "uglifier", "coffee-rails", "jquery-rails", "turbolinks", "jbuilder", "sdoc", "bcrypt", "byebug", "web-console", "spring"]
```

If the problem is that there are too many threads, how can I limit how many there are in bundler?

Edit: Tried to run `bundle install --jobs 1`, but it gave the same errors, meaning my original hunch was wrong.

Comment: [Here](http://bundler.io/v1.5/bundle_install.html) are options for bundler. Try `bundle install --jobs 1` (for a single thread only)

Comment: @maxpleaner Yeah, I tried it, but it gave the same error, even with verbose, which means that my hunch was wrong.

Comment: OP, have you seen this GitHub issue? https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4367 There are a number of solutions proposed: downgrading Bundler, adjusting your nproc config, etc.

Comment: @pdoherty926 THANK YOU! Downgrading to 1.11.2 from 1.12.1 fixed the problem!